# Spring 3.0 security not working with annotation based controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add authentication support to my Spring 3.0 web application but nothing from http:basic to more elaborate authentication is working. the examples provided in Spring documentation do not work.

is there a different way of enabling security when using annotated controllers?

I have springSecurityFilterChain mapping in web.xml, i've got spring security jar files in my library.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!--
        Key of the system property that should specify the root directory of this
        web app. Applied by WebAppRootListener or Log4jConfigListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>WebIDE.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Map URL for views: display /index instead of /app/index as
          suggested by the dispatcher -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


    <!-- Mapping required for the security feature to work -->
   <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- set up dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jnlp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    </web-app>
```

application-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- enable web security for defined roles -->

  <http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp' default-target-url='/'  />
  </http>


<!-- define test logins TO REMOVE -->
 <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="jimi" password="jimi" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <user name="bob" password="bob" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, logfile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${WebIDE.root}\WEB-INF\resources\WebIDE.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=512KB
# Keep three backup files.
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=3
# Pattern to output: date priority [category] - message
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

all my jsp files are saved in WEB-INF/views/

DEBUGGING INFO

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy] - Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'

DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'

DEBUG [org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy] - Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured successfully

DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'

DEBUG[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] - Adding web access control expression 'ROLE_USER',  for Ant [pattern='/']
DEBUG[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] - Adding web access control expression 'ROLE_USER', for org.springframework.security.web.util.AnyRequestMatcher@2433a1
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#6'

INFO [org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator] - Checking whether login URL '/spring_security_login' is accessible with your configuration
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator] - Default generated login page is in use
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0'
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0'
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0'
2010-11-29 07:57:58,744 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'

DEBUG [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default 

[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@ca2c3d]
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name 

[org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
INFO [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9316 ms
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter] - Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter] - Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy] - Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy] - Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured successfully
DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Initializing servlet 'app dispatcher'
INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - FrameworkServlet 'app dispatcher': initialization started
```

Comment: nothing happens. with spring security enabled, and all jar files added, when i load the system there are no "basic" login page. even if i define a login page, it is not displayed at all. I should also mention that I am only using one jsp and relies on dojo json calls for the different functionality. I'm not sure if that could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: i have updated the message above to add my web.xml and log4j.properties file

Comment: Try changing "log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, logfile" to "log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, logfile"

Comment: Why is springSecurityFilterChain related entries in web.xml commented?

Comment: Thanks nickdos, I made a couple of other changes on top of what you suggested and i can now get spring debug info. springSecurityFilterChain was temporarily commented out whilst working on other part of my application. I have updated my message with debugging information. it looks like a default login page was created but not displayed: DEBUG [org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator] - Default generated login page is in use

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Secured does not work in controller, but intercept-url seems to be working fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651119/secured-does-not-work-in-controller-but-intercept-url-seems-to-be-working-fine)

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen this Spring Security tutorial?

[Spring Security - Tutorial: Adding Security to Spring Petclinic](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html)

The first thing I would try, is to turn on DEBUG level logging for Spring Security:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Which will give you a better idea if some of your wiring is not working properly.

Comment: I referred to petclinic before reading spring documentation. I also used petclinic to set up my log4j files but that does not work either. i set up log4j in a property file. when i run my application it says "INFO: Initializing log4j from [C:\fypProg\WebIDE - 28nov\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties]" but nothing is being logged. Another thing... when i use log4j, spring ignores any updates made on my javascript. javascript code in netbeans and firebug are completely different.

Comment: i have updated the message above to add my web.xml and log4j.properties file

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure your web.xml has the right order of things. Add following to the very beginning of the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You already have the "ContextLoaderListener" in your configuration so you have to move it up. Let me know what happens after you done this. You might have to configure the "filterChainProxy" bean in the application context.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is and old question, it might be helpful to others.  I found dot(.) in the url causes Spring Security to fail.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128954/spring-mvc-annotation-based-controller-failed-to-find-request-handler-method) is my similar question I posted.