# Securing @Controller inconsistency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing *REST API* with *Spring MVC* and securing it with *Spring Security*. I have two URL's, one is */company/{id}* and the second one is */countries*. *ws* is my servlet mapping.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/ws/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

is configured, however when I try to access to */company/1* it passes me

```
11:17:19,751 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-10 AntPathRequestMatcher:matches:103 - Checking match of request : '/ws/company/1'; against '/ws/*'
11:17:19,751 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-10 FilterSecurityInterceptor:beforeInvocation:184 - Public object - authentication not attempted
```

and with /countries everything works fine. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651119/secured-does-not-work-in-controller-but-intercept-url-seems-to-be-working-fine) question and do use global security in my mvc related context. Can't figure out what's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mapping everything under `/ws/` using the ant style selector `**` which indicates to include everything within the specified URL, not just URLs within the specified URL.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/ws/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: @J-unior Glad I could help.  These ant style path mappings are used pretty heavily in Spring.