# Can't get @Secured working in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, restful-architecture

I'm using Spring MVC to expose RESTful services. I already enabled authentication via HTTPBasicAuthentication, and using `<security:http>` i can control which roles can access urls.

Now I want to use `@Secured` annotation. I tried to add it to Controller methods but it doesn't work. It simply does nothing.

Here is my `Controller` class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class HomeController {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

private static final String USERS = "/users";
private static final String USER = USERS+"/{userId:.*}";

    @RequestMapping(value=USER, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @Secured(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public @ResponseBody User signin(@PathVariable String userId) {
        logger.info("GET users/"+userId+" received");
        User user= service.getUser(userId);
        if(user==null)
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        return user;
    }
}
```

This is my `security-context.xml`:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</http>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin@somedomain.com" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user@somedomain.com" password="pswd"
                authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And my `root-context.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mypackage" />

<import resource="database/DataSource.xml"/> 

<import resource="database/Hibernate.xml"/>

<import resource="beans-context.xml"/> 

<import resource="security-context.xml"/>
```

All works fine, but If I add `@Secured`, it simply does nothing: I can access secured method with user@somedomain.com also, which hasn't ROLE_ADMIN privileges. 
I already tried to move `<security:global-method-security>` to `root-context.xml`, it doesn't work. I also tried to secure the same method via `<security:http>` tag, it works fine, but I want to use `@Secured` annotation.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I've also a `servlet-context.xml` and a `controllers.xml` config file in the appServlet subdirectory.

Here is `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />
```

And `controllers.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mose.emergencyalert.controllers" />

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />     

<beans:bean id="homeController" class="org.mose.emergencyalert.controllers.HomeController"/>
```

Comment: why do you have `security:` prefix for `global-method-security` where `authentication-manager` does not have?

Comment: cut/paste mistake, while moving the tag from root-context, sorry. However still not working.

Comment: Just to be clear - is your entire configuration in the root application context or is some in the child DispatcherServlet context as well? Also, is your Controller implementing any interface?

Comment: try forcing cglib proxies: <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />

Comment: I added Controller class definition, no interface implementation. In the appServlet subdirectory I have `servlet-context.xml` and `controllers.xml`. Maybe I've to specify `<global-method-security>` in  `serlvet-context.xml`?

Comment: Yes, you have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651119/secured-does-not-work-in-controller-but-intercept-url-seems-to-be-working-fine

Answer (score 9):

Solved, I added `<global-method-security>` tag in `servlet-context.xml`, instead of `security-context.xml`.

Here is the new `security-context.xml`:

```
<annotation-driven />

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

NB: now Eclipse warns me at the `<security:global-method-security>` line: "`advises org.mypackage.HomeController.signin(String, 
     Principal)`", proving  that `@Secured` is now working.

Comment: Thank you, did forget that these contexts are seperated!

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

Add this tag to your config file that contain ViewResolve config :
**dispatcher's xml NOT on your application's xml**
 
  `<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured annotations="enabled">`

[tuto](http://huahsin68.blogspot.com/2014/05/why-secured-and-preauthorize-isnt.html)