# @Secured annotation is not working for my Spring 3.1 based app in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-annotations

I am using Spring 3.1 and Spring Security 3.1 and JBoss EAP 6.

I have been trying to use the Spring security @Secured annotation, but it doesn't work. I think i have done things right, but clearly something is wrong.

I have tried @Secured on classes, methods, but really where I want it, is to be on the interface, which is what it states in Spring doc's.

**spring-security.xml file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

        <security:http auto-config="true">
        <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/logoutSuccess*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />      

        <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
        <security:form-login login-page="/test/login" 
                     login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
                     default-target-url="/test/testHome" 
                     authentication-failure-url="/test/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/test/logout" />
        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider>
                <security:user-service>
                    <security:user name="test_user" password="test" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                    <security:user name="test_admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                </security:user-service>
            </security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>

    </beans>
```

**spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config/>    
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.service"/>

    </beans>
```

**mvc-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.service"/>

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basenames">
                <list>
                    <value>mymessages</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**client-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

        <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.test.service.ws" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:/environment.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
            <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
            <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
            <property name="defaultUri" value="${test.webServiceTemplate.defaultUri}" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:/activedirectory.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
            <constructor-arg value="${test.activeDirectory.domain}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${test.activeDirectory.activeDirectoryServer}" />
            <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="tdrUserDetailsContextMapper" /> 
            <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />        
            <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
        </bean>  

        <bean id="tdrUserDetailsContextMapper" class="com.test.service.web.user.impl.UserDetailsContextMapperImpl" />   

    </beans>
```

**One of my interfaces**

```
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;

public interface TestService {

    @Secured ({"ROLE_XXX"})
    TestResponse getCustomer(TestRequest request);

}
```

Comment: Which beans are you actually using it on (it only works with Spring beans)? Also check [this FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context).

Comment: It's almost certainly the FAQ issue. Try moving your `global-method-security` into the web configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Luke Taylor, as you said, I moved the <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" /> 
into my mvc-config.xml file and this worked. I had tried about everything else. Thanks

Comment: Add this as the answer and I will complete it. Do you think I have my xml files structured and named correctly based on the above. I would like to also clean these up a little?

Comment: The organization is really up to you. You could also move your services out of the web context, which might be more logical. I'm going to recommend closing this as it's something that is already covered in a lot of other questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Secured does not work in controller, but intercept-url seems to be working fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651119/secured-does-not-work-in-controller-but-intercept-url-seems-to-be-working-fine)