# Spring MVC - Annotation based controller failed to find request handler method

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7

This has stopped working after I added a Spring Security filter.

Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE 
Spring Security 3.1.2.RELEASE 
Tomcat 7.0.37

The mapping is configured as expected when the app is deployed

```
INFO annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/countries],methods=[GET],params=[!countryCode],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.purpleleaf.proxy.rest.data.ProxyResponse com.purpleleaf.proxy.rest.service.reference.DefaultCountry.findAll()
```

The GET request is submitted.

```
GET http://localhost:8081/purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries?page=1&start=0&limit=25
```

The request parameters are added by ExtJS and it is not an issue as it was working without security.

The log for the GET request

```
DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/countries'; against '/*'
DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy: /countries?page=1&start=0&limit=25 has an empty filter list
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet: DispatcherServlet with name 'admin-spring' processing GET request for [//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries]
DEBUG annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Looking up handler method for path //purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries
DEBUG annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Did not find handler method for [//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries]
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Matching patterns for request [//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries] are [/**]
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: URI Template variables for request [//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries] are {}
DEBUG handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Mapping [//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@3f8050cf] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet: Last-Modified value for [//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countries] is: -1
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet: Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'admin-spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet: Successfully completed request
```

When the request is processed by web.filterChainProxy it is **/countries** but when it is process by annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping it is **//purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0/countires**

**purpleleaf-admin-1.0.0** is the folder where war file is unpaked.

web.xml has following servlet and filter mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin-spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any suggestion on how I can resolve this mapping?

Edit 1: Spring Security Configuration File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <beans:import resource="classpath*:applicationContext-CrowdClient.xml" />

<beans:bean id="crowdUserDetailsService" class="com.atlassian.crowd.integration.springsecurity.user.CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="crowdAuthenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="groupMembershipManager" ref="crowdGroupMembershipManager"/>
    <beans:property name="userManager" ref="crowdUserManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authorityPrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="crowdAuthenticationProvider" class="com.atlassian.crowd.integration.springsecurity.RemoteCrowdAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="crowdAuthenticationManager"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="httpAuthenticator"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="crowdUserDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref='crowdAuthenticationProvider' />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="crowdAuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/login.jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="crowdAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.atlassian.crowd.integration.springsecurity.CrowdSSOAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="httpAuthenticator" ref="httpAuthenticator"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_security_check"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean class="com.atlassian.crowd.integration.springsecurity.UsernameStoringAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?error=true"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="crowdLogoutHandler" class="com.atlassian.crowd.integration.springsecurity.CrowdLogoutHandler">
    <beans:property name="httpAuthenticator" ref="httpAuthenticator"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="/index.html"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="crowdLogoutHandler"/>
            <beans:ref bean="securityContextLogoutHandler"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout.html"/>
</beans:bean>

<http pattern='/*' security='none'/>
<!--http pattern='/scripts/*' security='none'/-->

<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="crowdAuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">

    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref='crowdAuthenticationProcessingFilter'/>
    <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref='logoutFilter'/>

    <!--intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_application-administrators"/-->
    <!--intercept-url pattern="/passwordHint.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/-->
    <!--security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/-->
</http>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: please post your spring security configuration file.

Comment: @shazinltc I have now added the security config into the question.  Though I have configured the security configuration, I have not restrict any path yet.

Comment: Please post complete spring security config file, it seems missing some content.

Comment: Please fix your servlet mapping to `/` (without *) and map security filter to servlet name, not URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was the purpleleaf-admin-**1.0.0** on the url. **util.AntPathRequestMatcher** could not resolve the path correctly when it contains a dot(.).

The class was not in the path until the security filter was added.